# Setting fixed navigation at the top of the form

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and I have a div as a container for 3 rows.

The 1st and the 3rd row will be fixed while the middle(content) is a big form and will be scrolled while the 1st and the 3rd row will be always visible.

I am having trouble making this help, can you please help.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="position: absolute;left:20%;right:5%;top:10%;z-index: 1000;">
            <div class="col-4">
                    <!-- Top navigation -->
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="navbar-example">
                        <div>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5%;">
            <input type="hidden" id="_token" >
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="box box-primary">
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <!-- form start -->
                    <form class="form-horizontal"
                          data-target="#navbar-example" id="adaptation_form">
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <div id="profileAnchor" class="box box-secondary">
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                                        <div class="panel-heading">Profile</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                        <!-- /.box-footer -->
                    </form>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <a type="button" href="{{ route('adapt.cancel', [$id]) }}" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                        <button id="create_dataset" name="create_dataset" type='submit'
                                class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the Top navigation and the footer to be fixed, I tried with position:fixed but then it overlaps the content when I scroll.

Screenshots for reference :
In the image below there is a header with Profile and Courses, I want that to be fixed the rest of the content if scrolled should still make the header fixed and visible.
[image]

I tried with position: fixed, however it overlaps when I scroll the content.
[image]

Comment: Could you share an image of what you want to achieve. You question and the code written isn't matching. I could definitely help you with this, if I could understand your problem :)

Comment: Hi @ImranRafiqRather I have added screenshots, hope they are helpful.

Comment: If you could use stackoverflow's code snippet tool to put your code. That would help us more to debug this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use class `sticky-top` to your `navbar which will always stick your navbar to the top. Next use` d-flex flex-column min-vh-100`to the body and add`mt-auto fixed-bottom`  to your footer. So your footer will be fixed at the bottom of page. Below is the working snippet

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body class="d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sticky top</a>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <p>
      What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
      recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The
      point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem
      Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
    </p>
  </section>
  <footer class="mt-auto fixed-bottom text-center text-white bg-dark pt-2 pb-2"> footer</footer>
</body>
```